# Can I achieve a wildcard % in the middle of a DataView RowFilter command?

Tags: c#, .net, dataview

I have this row filter text: `"[Name 1] = '" + forename + "%" + surname + "'"` which fails, but if I put the `%` at the beginning or end it's OK. Is there any way to achieve the same result (i.e. "any" string in the middle of the names)?

Full statement is:

```
dv = new DataView(MyDataTable, 
"[Name 1] = '" + forename + "%" + surname + "'", 
"", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Comment: Depending on what the goal is, the operator should be `LIKE` , not `=`, or the reserved wildcard `%` should be escaped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a free thougth, try:

```
dv = new DataView(MyDataTable, 
"[Name 1] = '" + forename + "%' AND [Name 1] = '%" + surname + "'", 
"", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

EDIT: some [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

"A wildcard is allowed at the start and end of a pattern, or at the end of a pattern, or at the start of a pattern. [...] Wildcard characters are not allowed in the middle of a string. For example, 'te*xt' is not allowed."

My guess would be it's for performance reasons (?)

Comment: Nice thought. Any idea why it doesn't allow it in the middle?