# C# asp.net Filter datatable with % just like sql server like : columtext like '%a%b%'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I Have a problem filtering my data table using %

I want to get the same result when I search string using SQL server query :

```
select PatientName
from table
where patientname like '%d%k%'
```

Result : 
Disney Kong
DK John
Donkey

How can I get the same result using a Datatable filter?

I have tried using :

```
tbl.Select("patientname like '%d%k%'", "PatientName DESC")
```

and get an error.

The syntax work well like this :

```
tbl.Select("patientname like '%d k%'", "PatientName DESC")
```

but it will not return the result that I want..

Can someone Help me?

this is my complete code :

```
    protected void cboProductMEIIT_ItemRequested(object o, RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        RadComboBox cboProductMEIIT = (RadComboBox)o;

        string sFindStr = e.Text.Trim();
        string sFilter = " AreaID = '" + Sumber + "' And DescriptionTrim Like '%" + sFindStr + "%'  ";


        cboProductMEIIT.DataSource = ((DataTable)Session["dtbAbbrev_" + Sumber]).Select(sFilter, "SequenceNo DESC, Description Asc").Take(15);
        cboProductMEIIT.DataBind();
    }
```

I set the session into datatable and i want to filter that datatable.

regards

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Error in Like operator: the string pattern '%d%k%' is invalid.

Comment: Looks like the wildcard characters are not supported the way you want in datatable.select. It only supports wildcard characters at start and/or end but not within the string. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

Comment: Is there an alternative to accomplish the same result as sql query?

Answer (score 2):

`DataTable.Select` cannot do it.

It is [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) under the heading "Wildcard Characters", that

> Wildcard characters are not allowed in the middle of a string. For example, 'te*xt' is not allowed.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289735/can-i-achieve-a-wildcard-in-the-middle-of-a-dataview-rowfilter-command

Comment: Is there an alternative to accomplish the same result as sql query?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use LINQ. If you're showing lines of code please use the `` tags.

LIKE in LINQ works a bit different then in SQL. Writing a LINQ query could be as following

```
var results = from c in db.tbl
where SqlMethods.Like(c.patientname, $"%{searchString}%")
select c;
```

and if needed an order

```
var results = from c in db.tbl
where SqlMethods.Like(c.patientname, $"%{searchString}%")
orderby c.patientname descending
select c;
```

Comment: i've edit my post with my codes. Can I do that using the code you gave?

Comment: If you are trying to preform a LIKE query, you cannot use Select. The code i provided you let you search in the database.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

replace your code

```
string sFilter = " AreaID = '" + Sumber + "' And DescriptionTrim Like '%" + sFindStr + "%'  ";
```

with

```
string sFilter = " AreaID = '" + Sumber + "' ";
                         if (sFindStr.IndexOf(" ") == -1) { sFilter = sFilter + " And DescriptionTrim Like '%" + sFindStr + "%' "; } else {
    int iSpc = sFindStr.IndexOf(" ");
    string sA = sFindStr.Substring(0, iSpc);
    string sB = sFindStr.Substring(iSpc + 1, sFindStr.Length - (iSpc + 1));
    sFilter = sFilter + " And DescriptionTrim Like '%" + sA + "%' And DescriptionTrim Like '%" + sB + "%'  "; }
```

not solved, but little help..